# Node-sass Python version compatibility

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, node-sass

I am using 4.14.1 in my project and with Node 14. I need to know which version of Python is needed to run node-gyp.

I also went through the repo link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass, but not able to find the details of Python version.

Comment: I strongly recommend you follow the advice in the first paragraph of the link you included and move to Dart SASS.

Comment: If you want to know about the requirements for node-gyp, why are you looking at the documentation for node-sass instead of the documentation for node-gyp: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp ?

Comment: Mainline support for node 14 ended some time ago. It only gets security updates now, and not for much longer. You should upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Install and use `sass` instead of `node-sass`.
Because `node-sass` is now deprecated.

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install sass
```

It works all the same (no additional changes needed)

Answer (score 1):

Change it to sass and remove node-sass